# LifecycleException: No UserDatabase component found under key

Tags: tomcat

**This is My servlet.xml file**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource auth="Container"
 driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
     initialSize="5"
       maxActive="120"
         maxIdle="5"
         maxWait="5000"
            name="jdbc/EPRT_DEV"
        password="admin"
             url="jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/password@192.168.178.83:1521:XE"
        username="system"
         factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
        pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<!--
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
      resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
-->
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
    resourceName="jdbc/EPRT_DEV"/>
```

**This is my context.xml file**

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/EPRT_DEV"
            global="jdbc/EPRT_DEV"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Have any idea? Please help me ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no file called `servlet.xml` that Tomcat recognizes. I hope you mean `CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`.

Second, your `<Resource>` definition is in complete shambles: you need to read the [Tomcat documentation on Resource definitions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource%20Definitions). `MemoryUserDatabaseFactory` is intended to read a file specified by the `path` attribute of the `<Resource>` definition, but you appear to be trying to use an Oracle database for authentication.

Likewise, you are using a `UserDatabaseRealm` (which is intended to be paired with `MemoryUserDatabaseRealm`)' and then trying to connect it to your broken DataSource.

If you want to use Oracle, then remove the `factory` and `pathname` attributes from your `<Resource>` definition and change your `className` in your `<Realm>` to be `org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm`. Read the [DataSourceRealm documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#DataSourceRealm), too, because it's configured very differently than what you have here.

If you have to re-post, please include the full stack trace of any errors you encounter, and edit your post to include proper details instead of doing everything from memory.

Comment: Thanks its work for me when i change the className in the Realm tag as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

May be u guys would have wrote something that not allowable in  tomcat-users.xml

earlier i added admin inside "roles" and i got same error..i just removed that roles from tomcat-users.xml

Comment: This was a problem for my tomcat-users.xml configuration - it wasn't parseable (xml errors)